How to glue the Milky Way art piece?
I am getting ready to build the Milky Way art set that's meant to be hung and displayed. I am fearful of gluing in the process, in case I make a mistake and have to go back a few steps. This happens to me occasionally while building due to ADHD, or merely because pages are stuck together in the booklet. Is there a topical spray glue or sealant I can use after it's built to ensure it will stay together?

The recommendations in the suggested duplicate are all permanent glues, which contradict the requirement OP made regarding being able to go back a few steps in case a mistake is made.

Normally the clutch power between LEGO bricks is enough to keep them together - after all, the piece was designed to hold up under normal use (i.e. being hung). If you really want to protect it against stronger forces (for example something or somebody brushing against it), you could use a transparent spray-on glue after everything has been assembled. There are also water-soluble glues that allow one to remedy any mistakes.
